# Como usar side-nav do Materialize?

Tags: html, css, html5, materialize, sidebar

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer um menu responsivo para meu portfólio, estou usando o do materialize mas quando coloco ele fixo o side-nav da versão mobile buga, fica todo escuro e não da para clicar nos itens, aqui está a imagem de como fica quando está com a classe navbar-fixed

[image: Side nav fixo]

e aqui está uma imagem para mostrar como funciona normalmente sem colocar ele fixo

[image: navbar não fixo]

para fazer este menu eu assisti este vídeo: 2.- Tutorial Materialize: NAVBAR 
do canal Brajan Montes Perez no youtube, não coloquei o link pq se não não tem como colocar o código html

meu código aqui (retirei o corpo)

menulateral

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"     rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-1">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Eduardo Moya Simões</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Habilidades</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Portifólio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Currículo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                    <li><a href="">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Habilidades</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Portifólio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Currículo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
   <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
   <script src="js/materialize.min.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.parallax').parallax();
    });
   </script>
   <script>
     $( document ).ready(function(){
     $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
   })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontecia a mesma coisa para mim e descobri q é por causa do z-index da classe `.navbar-fixed`.
Para resolver apenas insira em seu css:

```
.navbar-fixed {
  z-index: 998;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque está usando 2 ready(function)??

Tente fazer assim:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  $('.parallax').parallax();
});
</script>
```

Comment: não deu não, mas vlw

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="">Início</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Habilidades</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portifólio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Currículo</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

Você deve apenas colocar o código abaixo depois da div com a classe "navbar-fixed":

Início

Habilidades

Portifólio

Currículo

Contato

Answer (score 0):

Aqui estava bugando também, eu resolvi tirando a ancora da ação de dentro do nav, o meu ficou assim.

```
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-1">
            <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Eduardo Moya Simões</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Habilidades</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portifólio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Currículo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                <li><a href="">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Habilidades</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portifólio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Currículo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>  
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Não sei porque isso acontece, mas pelo menos aqui resolveu, porém depois tive que reposicionar a âncora da ação

Answer (score 0):

Tem que definir um z-index menor para o sidenav-overlay em relação ao sidenav (obs: o nome das classes podem mudar de acordo com a versão do materializecss).

Inspecione o sidenav e anote seu z-index, mude no seu custom css, ou até no próprio css do materialize, o z-index do sidenav-overlay para que seja menor que o sidenav em si.

Answer (score 0):

Tive que alterar o z-index no CSS para -1

```
.sidenav-overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0;
height: 120vh;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
z-index: -1;
display: none;
```

}